# calendar as a popup in ag-grid cell

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date, calendar, ag-grid

I am using ag-grid to display a list of columns. One of the columns contains the date section.

User should be able to edit the row and use calendar to select a particular date. Once a date is selected, it will get updated in the cell.

Any idea how to make it achievable ?

As per Ag-grid, we have to use cellEditor rather than cellRenderer to edit a cell and show calendar at every cell for selection of a date

https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-editing/index.php
They have given few examples of how we can use Celleditor. Can someone please let me know how to use calendar for each cells of the 'date' column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got the following answer from ag-grid team

editing of dates is not provided out of the box. you will need to create your own cell editor for dates.

details on how to do cell editors is here:
https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-.../index.php

Comment: The link to the cell editors is 404. https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-editor/

Answer (score 0):

I use bootstrap, and this has property type="date". I have one list "ListDataSource", this has one file call celDate and contains this html:

When i send this list to api.setRowData(ListDataSource), the grid create the date input.

See you.

Comment: Hi, Can you please elaborate more or show an example if possible.